# ChartJS só começa o gráfico quando altero o zoom da página

Tags: javascript, chartjs

Gente, por algum motivo meu gráfico feito em chartJS só mostra os dados quando eu aperto ctrl+shift+i pra abrir o console ou quando altero o zoom da página, o que não é algo muito interessante pra um usuário.

Estou testando no meu notebook. Eis o código:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="dashboard_graph">

            <div class="row x_title">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3>Network Activities</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">

              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'bar',
     data: {
         labels: horizontal,
         datasets: [{
             label: '# of Votes',
             data: vertical,
             backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
             borderColor: borderColor,
             borderWidth: 1
         }]
     },
     options: {
         scales: {
             yAxes: [{
                 ticks: {
                     beginAtZero:false
                 }
             }]
         }
     }
 });
```

Omiti as  variáveis do chartJs porque acho que não vem ao caso como elas são preenchidas. Será que tem a ver com a div que envolve o canvas do chartjs?

Obrigado!

Comment: Poste o css desse html possívelmente nele tem alguma "@media screen" causando isso.

Comment: Não entendo nada de ChartJS, mas você já tentou colocar aquele "beginAtZero" para "true" ao invés do false? Só um palpite mesmo.

Comment: @inovapixel sim. Não altera em nada.

Comment: @RafaelSalomão vou olhar e posto